# SQL (Postgres): ON vs WHERE for better performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, join, select

I have a person and a task table. The task table is much bigger and contains millions of rows.

With the following (fast) SQL statement I get a list of tasks for a given person:

```
select p.name, t.name
from person p
join task t on t.person_id = p.id 
where p.id = 1234
```

Unfortunately, I need to work with the following (equivalent but slow) SQL statement:

```
select p.name, t.name
from person p
join task t on 1 = 1
where t.id in (
  select t.id
  from task t
  where t.person_id = p.id )
and p.id = 1234
```

Why does the second statement take about 20 seconds, while the first only runs for less than a second. Can I use an index or something to speed up the second statement as well? I cannot change the SQL statement.

Comment: I'm a bit baffled.  What you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Different queries, different results (depending on data.)

Comment: The result is the same, shouldn't the execution plan be the same as well?

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: Writing `from person p join task t on 1 = 1` is ridiculous - why on earth would you write that?

Comment: Why do you have to work with a slow query when you know how to write and use a fast query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.name, t.name
from person p
join task t on t.person_id = p.id 
where p.id = 1234
```

- This is `INNER JOIN`
- It uses proper join conditions and `p.id = 1234` further reduces the cost of the query

..

```
select p.name, t.name
from person p
join task t on 1 = 1
where t.id in (
  select t.id
  from task t
  where t.person_id = p.id )
and p.id = 1234
```

- This is `CROSS JOIN` which will generate m*n records
- Here, `p.id = 1234` is used but still number of records will be (number of records satisfying `p.id = 1234`) * (Number of records in `Tasks` table)
- `IN` sub-query is corelated query which takes much time as query will be executed once for each record.
- Each expression/statements used in this query is costly. Hence, It is taking time.

Comment: This means that it is not simply possible to change the execution plan by adding an index or so?

Comment: Why not? If there is index on `t.person_id` and `p.id` as I assume it will be as one is PK and one is FK then it will be helpful but your second query is costlier than first one in any case.